# In Visual studio, I want it to open another form first when I debug, how do I do this?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've made a mistake on my coursework and I need to change it so VS opens another form when I debug it

Can someone be nice enough to help me do this?

For example, right now it's going straight into Employee Login when I need it to open a startup page first..

How do I do this? Would appreciate help thanks.

Comment: Yes sir it is a windows form application , I haven't tried anything else as I'm lost but what information do you require ?

Answer (score 5):

You did not say which language you are using so I will give you examples in C# and VB.net

In C# you have a `Program.cs` file you can edit the `Application.Run` statement to change your startup form:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1()); // Change this to your Startup Form's Name.
    }
}
```

It is located in your Solution Explorer.

[image]

if VB.net you can change the Startup form in Project Property's

[image]

If neither of these are what you are looking for please edit your question with more information on what you are trying to do, what you tried what language you are using etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, sorry I am using c sharp.

Comment: Mind telling me where I can find the file  program.cs please? I'll try this tomorrow

Comment: It is part of your solution, if it isn't visible you might need to click the icon in your solution explorer to show all files. When I get my computer fired back up I will post a screen shot.